# How to update a value from a specific row and column in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm building an application that have a DataGridView and sometimes during the program execution I need to update a value from a specific row and column, because this value contains data related with the quantity of some item.

So to exemplify imagine you have this DataGridView:

```
       0          1
  +----------+----------+
  |   Item   | Quantity |
  +----------+----------+
0 | Candy L  |    1     |
  +----------+----------+
```

And I need to add +1 to the row 0 and column 1. So I'd have this as result.

```
       0          1
  +----------+----------+
  |   Item   | Quantity |
  +----------+----------+
0 | Candy L  |    2     |
  +----------+----------+
```

I already did some stuff:

```
int rowIndex = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dataGridViewLista.Rows)
{
    if (dgvRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString() == "Candy")
        // Here I'd update the row (at this point I already have the row index)
    rowIndex++;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the Quantity cell's value, parse it to integer or respective type and then add `1` to it assign the result back to `Cell.Value` property like:

```
if (dgvRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString() == "Candy")
{
 int qty = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue);
 qty += 1;
 dgvRow[0].Cells[1].Value = qty;
}
```

Its better if you parse using [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method to avoid exceptions

Comment: Habib could also please tell me how to update this row at the DataGridView? Also Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Zignd, where are you calling your loop ? it should change the value in GridView, try after binding source to the grid.

Comment: Never mind Habib the row updates automatically. Thanks you really helped me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use somtehing like this:

```
int rowIndex = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dataGridViewLista.Rows)
{
      if (dgvRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString() == "Candy")
      {
             int value;
             if(int.TryParse(dgvRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue, out value))
                   dgvRow.Cells[1].Value = value + 1;
      }
      rowIndex++;
}
```